# why are noSQL databases more scalable than SQL?

Tags: sql, nosql, scalability

Recently I read a lot about noSQL DBMSs. I understand CAP theorem, ACID rules, BASE rules and the basic theory. But didn't find any resources on why is noSQL scalable more easily than RDBMS (e.g. in case of a system that requires lots of DB servers)? I guess that keeping constraints and foreign keys cost resources and when a DBMS is distributed, it is a lot more complicated. But I expect there's a lot more than this.

Can someone please explain how noSQL/SQL affects scalability?

Comment: I think you may get better results asking on  [programmers.stackexchange.com](http://programmers.stackexchange.com)

Comment: Because most of the time they sacrifice consistency and durability for speed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It really depends on your problem, each database type has its advantages and nether SQL nor noSQL is better at scaling, they are different.  It all depends on the data you have and if your data is relation in nature then SQL may be better, if your data is document based (no defined schema) then noSQL may be better.  We use both types of databases in our product, we have lots of different data and some fits into SQL and some into noSQL.

What kind of scale are you considering?  Parallel access, handling large number of queries or very large data handling?  Your question is very broad, it's a bit tough to answer without knowing what problems you are trying to solve.

Comment: My question is more a theoretical one. I just want to understand the concept behind hypothetical better scalability of noSQL over SQL.

Comment: It really depends on data.  If say you have a lot of JSON data where fields are never consistent, for example a store with products that may have size or dimensions or color but not always, in this case you would key the data by SKU and each data element would be unique.  Adding products would be trivial and would scale way better; since in SQL you would have to create a table with all possible columns and many will be null yet it will get very complex especially if you have to span multiple tables and then do JOINs.  In this example noSQL would be far faster and scale much better. (more)

Comment: In SQL you can also have a concept of EAV (which is a table that stores attributes and name/value pairs which scales fine for inserts but is awful for retrieval, this I know from first hand experience).  If your data is fixed and you know what it lokos like, SQL can do well with indexing and fast lookup/inserts.  SQL has longevity on its side, for last 30+ years DB companies have developed a lot of technology around indexing, clustering and caching for RDBS, noSQL is getting there but it's not yet mature.  DB companies are starting to make hybrid table schemas as a result (more)

Comment: so you can have both relational and document based in one database.

Answer (score 0):

The performance of SQL/noSQL is not measured at conceptual levels. In fact, when the relational model (more correctly said than SQL) came by, it was demised as non-efficient, and then it took over the world. In computer science, what is assessed is the time complexity of specific algorithms (using specific structures).

In databases, of any type, multiple data structures with multiple operations (insert, delete, search) are used. Even the same operation for the same data structure might use different algorithms, thus provide different performance. Different RDBMSes might use different data structures/algorithms or variations.

The same is even more valid for noSQL databases, of which there are different types (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NoSQL).

Therefore, I don't think it makes sense to compare performance at such high level. You need to look at concrete algorithms and choose depending on the needs of your problem.

Consider also that some people are successfully implementing noSQL in RDBMs, in the sense of schema-less models, with large amounts of data: http://backchannel.org/blog/friendfeed-schemaless-mysql

Finally, a perhaps more subjective opinion, in concrete terms I am only aware that performance makes a difference when you have to change the schema. When tables are big, most RDBMs struggle with a change. This is not to say there is something conceptually wrong with them or inferior to noSQL. It just was not a problem since designs used to be seen as stable.

RDBMSes are starting to adapt, see eg. dynamic columns in MariaDB: https://kb.askmonty.org/en/dynamic-columns/